# How do I process a nested list?

Tags: python, parsing, list

Suppose I have a bulleted list like this:

```
* list item 1
* list item 2 (a parent)
** list item 3 (a child of list item 2)
** list item 4 (a child of list item 2 as well)
*** list item 5 (a child of list item 4 and a grand-child of list item 2)
* list item 6
```

I'd like to parse that into a nested list or some other data structure which makes the parent-child relationship between elements explicit (rather than depending on their contents and relative position). For example, here's a list of tuples containing an item and a list of its children (and so forth):

**Edit**: Hopefully, a more correct list example, where each element in the list is a tuple containing: a bullet's text and, if applicable, a list of children (in the same form).

```
    [('list item 1',),
     ('list item 2', [('list item 3',), ('list item 4', [('list item 5',)])]
     ('list item 6',)]
```

```
[('list item 1',),
 ('list item 2', [('list item 3',), ('list item 4', [('list item 5',)])]),
 ('list item 6',)]
```

I've attempted to do this with plain Python and some experimentation with Pyparsing, but I'm not making progress. I'm left with two major questions:

1. What's the strategy I need to employ to make this work? I know recursion is part of the solution, but I'm having a hard time making the connection between this and, say, a Fibonacci sequence.
2. I'm certain I'm not the first person to have done this, but I don't know the terminology of the problem to make fruitful searches for more information on this topic. What problems are related to this so that I can learn more about solving these kinds of problems in general?

Comment: I think if you can post your attempt here, people might be able to help you better!

Comment: are you attempting to parse org-mode files? Maybe you can take inspiration from orgnode and watch how he have done the parsing.
http://members.optusnet.com.au/~charles57/GTD/orgnode.html

Comment: @Lazer: I'm sorry, but I don't really have a useful sample of my attempt. In my frustration I wasn't checking into version control and what's left of my attempt isn't running. =\


@pygabriel: I'm not trying to parse org-mode, but thank you for the link. I'll definitely spend some time reviewing that soon. It may prove inspirational. If it's valuable, what I'm trying to do is make and use a super-simple checklist format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't parse your desired result -- it seems to have more open parentheses than corresponding closed ones and I don't understand the logic behind it.

To make a tree structure explicit, what about, e.g.:

```
data = '''* list item 1
* list item 2
** list item 3
** list item 4
*** list item 5
* list item 6'''.splitlines()

class Node(object):
  def __init__(self, payload):
    self.payload = payload
    self.children = []
  def show(self, indent):
    print ' '*indent, self.payload
    for c in self.children:
      c.show(indent+2)

def makenest(linelist):
  rootnode = Node(None)
  stack = [(rootnode, 0)]
  for line in linelist:
    for i, c in enumerate(line):
      if c != '*': break
    stars, payload = line[:i], line[i:].strip()
    curlev = len(stars)
    curnod = Node(payload)
    while True:
      parent, level = stack[-1]
      if curlev > level: break
      del stack[-1]
    # a child node of the current top-of-stack
    parent.children.append(curnod)
    stack.append((curnod, curlev))
  rootnode.show(0)

makenest(data)
```

The `show` method of course exists just for the purpose of verifying that the part about parsing the strings and creating the tree has worked correctly.  If you can specify more precisely exactly how it is that you want to transform your tree into nested tuples and lists, I'm sure it will be easy to add to class `Node` the appropriate (and probably recursive) method -- so, could you please give this missing specification...?

**Edit**: since the OP has clarified now, it does, as predicted, become easy to satisfy the spec.  Just add to `class Node` the following method:

```
  def emit(self):
    if self.children:
      return (self.payload,
              [c.emit() for c in self.children])
    else:
      return (self.payload,)
```

and change the last three lines of the code (last one of `makenest`, a blank one, and the module-level call to `makenest`) to:

```
  return [c.emit() for c in rootnode.children]

print(makenest(data))
```

(The parentheses after `print` are redundant but innocuous in Python 2, required in Python 3, so I put them there just in case;-).

With these tiny changes, my code runs as requested, now emitting

```
[('list item 1',), ('list item 2', [('list item 3',), ('list item 4', [('list item 5',)])]), ('list item 6',)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alex. As requested, I've edited my question with a more correct example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Let me know if that clears things up.

Comment: Thanks for this response. This is the method I ended up going with and it's working out great. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In the view of search algorithm, the bullet you give is actually a sequence generated by Depth-First-Search. So my strategy is just to rebuild the tree structure with the dfs-sequence.

Following is the python code:

```
from collections import deque
def dfsBullet(bullet,depth):
    """
       parse the subtree with depth and the startnode of bullet[0]
    """
    li = []
    if depth != 0:
            item = bullet.popleft()
            li.append(item.split(' ',1)[1])
    while (len(bullet) != 0):
            item = bullet[0]
            #apply same algo to the child node
            if len(item.split(' ',1)[0]) > depth:
                    sublist = dfsBullet(bullet, len(item.split(' ')[0]))
            #we have traverse all childnode, so go back 
            else:
                    return li
            #add child tree to the list
            li.append(sublist)
    return li
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the current "depth" you're parsing at.

- If the depth of the next line is more than the current depth, recursively call the parser with the new depth, then add the result from that call to the current list.
- If the depth of the next line is equal to the current depth, add it to the current list.
- If the depth of the next line is less than the current depth, return the current list.