# 1D list to a complex nested? Indentation to parent-child relation

Tags: python, list, parent-child

The first list shows indentation levels of lines. The second one adds the parent child relationship. Using python how do I get from the first to the second?

```
indent=[0,1,2,2,2,3,2,3,4,5,5,5,4,2,1,0,1,1]

parent_child=[[0,[1,[2,2,[2,[3]],[2,[3,[4,[5,5,5],4]]],2],1]],[0,[1,1]]]
```

Here is my code fragment so far:

```
pc=[]
for i in indent: 
    if i > pc[i-1]: 
        append
    if i == pc[i-1]: 
        if i+1 > i+1: 
            append
            extend
```

the tricky part for me is getting ...2,[2,[3]] and not ..2,2,[3]

```
lastindent = -1
print ("open list")
for pos, i in enumerate(indent):
    currchange = i-lastindent
    try:
        nextindent = indent[pos+1]
    except(IndexError):
        print('close all lists')
    nextchange = nextindent-i

    if currchange >0:
        print(" "*i+"open list (rule 1)")
        print(" "*i,i)

    if currchange==0 and nextchange==0:
        print(" "*i+" (rule 2)",i)

    if currchange== 0 and nextchange==1:
        print(" "*i+"open list (rule 3)")
        print(" "*i,i)

    if nextchange < 0:
        print("Close (rule 4)")

    if currchange < 0:
        print ("Close (rule 5")
        print(" "*i,i)
    ##needs more and accurate rules to get the nesting and closing right.

    lastindent = i
```

Some more unfinished code for illustration, nested HTML list is probably a better comparison.

Comment: Please show us what you have so far.

Comment: ...and please explain why `2,[2,[3]]` is correct, and `2,2,[3]` is not.

Comment: very sketchy code:
`    pc=[]
    for i in indent:
        if i > pc[i-1]:
            append...
        if i == pc[i-1]:
             if i+1 >i+1:
                  append..
        extend..
` 
2,[2,[3]] shows that node three deep belongs to 2, for example think of nested <sections> in HTML  there would be a section block around [2,[3]] and one around [3].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: @Prune, sorry, I know, I cant get any code n here decently, I can only edit for 5 minutes, I utterly lack vocabulary, english is not my native language and i don't know what more to explain.

Comment: Write what you need to say elsewhere.  With your 5-minute limit, cut and paste that text into your question.  We can correct the formatting and English for you.  The important part is to show your effort, and exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: This code has a problem when i=0; you'll compare against pc[-1], the last element ... and there isn't any on the first iteration.

Comment: Added som more code. It needs more rules, clearly. Is this the right approach? Wanting to represent the indnetation of an outline by the nesting of lists.

Comment: May have found it 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982992/how-do-i-process-a-nested-list